# Nill error was displayed when get the presenting VC

Tags: swift, swift4

In blue color's VC.
I try to get presenting VC instance.
So, write the code like below.
But, Xcode displayed "Unwrapping optional error".
What should i do for solve my problem.

[image]

```
/// In Blue View Controller of Image :)

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.pagingBeforeViewController()
}

func pagingBeforeViewController(){
    let mainVC = self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController as! MainViewController
    print(mainVC.aaa)
}
```

/// Error log 
[image]

Comment: There is not enough code here to tell you what is wrong, you need to post up more. (I didn't down vote you).

Answer (score 0):

I need only one code before get instance.
That is below code.

```
let preVc = mainVC.viewControllers[mainVC.viewControllers.count-1] as! MainViewController
```

If use Navigation Controller, we must find the VC history from Navigation VC.

Apparently, Navigation VC seems to have been holding the previous screen transition records.